# Change input css with jQuery/Ajax in different forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the same page i have two forms:

```
function fk(frm,ipt)
{
    document.frm.ipt.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
}
<div>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">
</form>
</div>
```

How can i change the css of input1 in form1 with jQuery/Ajax? Is that even possible?

UPDATE: if i try to pass the parameters to function, wont work. But, if i put like this

```
document.form1.input1.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
```

it works. Any help here?

Comment: ID's should be unique, just thought I would point that out before you run into more problems. Also why not just use `CSS` to change the styles? Are you wanting to change the styles after a specific event? If so I would recommend you update your question and explain in more detail what you wish to achieve. - *Blunt answer: Yes it is possible to change the style(s) using jQuery.*

Comment: Sorry for not explain this correctly. Yes, i want to change after one event. If the user dont type anything in one input, i will change the background color of the empty input. Then, when the user click in the empty input, i want to change the color back to the original. The thing here is that just one form is visible by time. I change this dynamicaly, by selection in radio buttons and i only test the visible form.

Comment: So basically you want to validate a form and change the background of the required inputs if submitted empty? If this is correct can you show what you have tried so far and explain the issue you have with the current source code and I will be happy to help you fix the problem and explain any changes needed or made to the source code to give you solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Assuming that the input is already verified and the background changed to red, i created one function to do the change back:

function fk(frm,ipt)
{
 document.frm.ipt.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
}

<div>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" onClick="fk('form1','input1');">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" onClick="fk('form2','input1');">
</form>
</div>

Comment: But, when i try to pass the parameters to function, wont work. if i trade 
"document.frm.ipt.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';" 
for 
"document.form1.input1.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';" 
it works.

Comment: Now I'm lost.... Please update your question and explain what you wish to achieve also explain the steps you want to take for your source code to take and then maybe someone can help you but as your questions stands at the moment it isn't clear enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS selector,

```
$('#form1 #input1').css()
```

to select it, but NewToJs is right use unique HTML ID's for each input even if they are not in the same form.

However, if you are trying to apply this to many elements, I would define a event handler function like this.

```js
$("input").focus(function(){
  // on focus
  $(this).css("background-color", "#bcbcbc");
});

$("input").blur(function(){
  if(this.value.length >= 1){
     // has a value
     $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
   }else{
     // is empty
     $(this).css("background-color", "red");
   }
});
```

That way you can have one function for each focus(user cursor in input) and blur(user left input), check the value and assign the color you want. The this variable refers to the input that was interacted with.

Comment: Note that that this.value.length is not the best logic to figure out if it has a value, they could enter a space etc, but it should get you started

Comment: i try this, but without sucess

Answer (score 0):

Option two: CSS only

Using the 'required' attribute in HTML will make elements required to be filled,

```
<input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" required />
```

And then use the css selectors Input:invalid or input:valid to assign styles

```
input:invalid, textarea:invalid { 
    background-color:red;
}

input:valid, textarea:valid {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. In fact, I would like the color change to occur in an event onClick